# REST - Get expanded property data for use in angular

Tags: rest, angularjs, api, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to figure out how to get the expanded property data and be able to use that data in my angular code.

REST call to get expanded property Data:

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages/KB')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Associated XML data

```
<m:properties>
                    <d:FileSystemObjectType m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:FileSystemObjectType>
                    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">13</d:Id>
                    <d:ContentTypeId>0x010100C568DB</d:ContentTypeId>
                    <d:Title>Test 2</d:Title>
                    <d:Comments m:null="true" />
                    <d:PublishingContactId m:type="Edm.Int32">10</d:PublishingContactId>
                    <d:PublishingContactEmail m:null="true" />
                    <d:PublishingContactName m:null="true" />
                    <d:PublishingContactPicture m:null="true" />
                    <d:PublishingPageLayout m:type="SP.FieldUrlValue">
                        <d:Description>Article Layout</d:Description>
                        <d:Url>/masterpage/ArticleLayout.aspx</d:Url>
                    </d:PublishingPageLayout>
                    <d:PublishingIsFurlPage m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:PublishingIsFurlPage>
                    <d:SeoBrowserTitle m:null="true" />
                    <d:SeoMetaDescription m:null="true" />
                    <d:SeoKeywords m:null="true" />
                    <d:RobotsNoIndex m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:RobotsNoIndex>
                    <d:PublishingPageContent>&lt;p&gt;????????????&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</d:PublishingPageContent>
                    <d:ArticleByLine m:null="true" />
                    <d:ArticleStartDate m:null="true" />
                    <d:PublishingImageCaption m:null="true" />
                    <d:Hints m:null="true" />
                    <d:Operational_x0020_Role m:type="Collection(Edm.String)">
                        <d:element>Financial Management</d:element>
                    </d:Operational_x0020_Role>
                    <d:Modules>General Accounting</d:Modules>
                    <d:Procedure_x0020_ID m:null="true" />
                    <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">13</d:ID>
                    <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-08-25T15:32:52</d:Created>
                    <d:AuthorId m:type="Edm.Int32">10</d:AuthorId>
                    <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-10-03T10:43:58</d:Modified>
                    <d:EditorId m:type="Edm.Int32">9</d:EditorId>
                    <d:OData__CopySource m:null="true" />
                    <d:CheckoutUserId m:null="true" />
                    <d:OData__UIVersionString>3.0</d:OData__UIVersionString>
                    <d:GUID m:type="Edm.Guid">ff929745-eb90-496f-80c4-011012e9f01b</d:GUID>
</m:properties>
```

When the angular code below runs the module portion is showing undefined although there is an associated tag in the expanded data properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.2/lodash.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var moduleServiceUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages/KB')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields";
        var appVar = angular.module('listApp', []);

        appVar.controller('controller1', ['$scope', '$http', function controller1($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: moduleServiceUrl,
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.items = data.d.results;
                $scope.modules = _.groupBy(data.d.results, 'Modules');
            });
        }])
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <hr />
    <div ng-app="listApp" class="ng-app" id="ng-app">
        <div id="App1" ng-controller="controller1">
            <div ng-repeat="(module, items) in modules">
                <p><strong>{{module}}</strong></p>
                <p ng-repeat="item in items" style="padding-left:10px;">
                    <a ng-href="{{item.ServerRelativeUrl}}">{{item.Title}}</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint:

```
/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages/KB')/Files?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

returns [`SP.FileCollection` resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246040.aspx) but `Modules` property belongs to `SP.ListItem` resource, that is the reason why Lodash `groupBy` returns `undefined`.

**Solution**

Replace the line:

```
$scope.modules = _.groupBy(data.d.results, 'Modules');
```

with

```
$scope.modules = _.groupBy(data.d.results, 'ListItemAllFields.Modules');
```